# Breaking up combined data into several smaller data sets

Tags: list-manipulation, data-structures

I have one combined data with first number as the x-value and the remaining as different y-axis values (y1,y2,y3...). How do I break this combined list, data= (x,y1,y2,y3...) into smaller lists, such that data1=(x,y1), data2=(x,y2), data3=(x,y3) and so on. A sample data is provided below. There are 13 different y-values corresponding to each x-value (0.020024338, etc)

```
data = {{0.020024338, 0.46718468, 0.47932421, 0.4963509, 0.54065813, 
   0.65672949, 0.90251868, 1.3993448, 2.0366537, 2.7787049, 3.5291491,
    4.1795025, 4.7176233, 5.2050893}, {0.022380134, 0.46261264, 
   0.47904547, 0.48048812, 0.53233204, 0.63802768, 0.87323611, 
   1.2855847, 1.8349797, 2.4843739, 3.0854011, 3.6431969, 4.0993234, 
   4.5086694}, {0.024735928, 0.46659667, 0.47086932, 0.48182777, 
   0.53003113, 0.60881906, 0.82828889, 1.1792591, 1.6458275, 
   2.1951179, 2.7178107, 3.1922793, 3.6018543, 
   3.9553359}, {0.027091718, 0.46147435, 0.4661452, 0.47106584, 
   0.51119942, 0.58587206, 0.77147002, 1.0795141, 1.5085768, 
   1.9689408, 2.4348231, 2.8437078, 3.2039729, 
   3.5031466}, {0.029447506, 0.45854677, 0.46537594, 0.4661371, 
   0.50055295, 0.57566797, 0.72922597, 1.006301, 1.3908136, 1.8015069,
    2.2057531, 2.5789405, 2.8856884, 3.136435}, {0.031803289, 
   0.45134029, 0.45601075, 0.46374043, 0.49128087, 0.55187622, 
   0.69920774, 0.95526727, 1.2911787, 1.6753659, 2.0387226, 2.3660197,
    2.6352631, 2.8969679}, {0.034159069, 0.44936824, 0.45563798, 
   0.46621482, 0.48637763, 0.54613861, 0.68024646, 0.91613335, 
   1.2340513, 1.5942974, 1.92385, 2.2354871, 2.5057308, 2.720232}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way to accomplish this:

```
op = data[[All, {1, #}]] & /@ Range[2, Length@data[[1]]];
```

Visualize:

```
ListLinePlot[op, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can collect them in different variables as follows:

```
Evaluate[Symbol /@ ("data" <> ToString[#] & /@ Range@Length@op)] = op;
```

Now: `data1` gives

> ```
> {{0.020024338, 0.46718468}, {0.022380134, 0.46261264}, {0.024735928, 0.46659667},
>  {0.027091718, 0.46147435}, {0.029447506, 0.45854677}, {0.031803289, 0.45134029}, 
>  {0.034159069, 0.44936824}}
> ```

Comment: @thils, Can you confirm if this is what you want?

Comment: I am not after the combined plot, the output required is of the form:  data1={{x1,y11},{x2,y12},{x3,y13}...}; data2={{x1,y21},{x2,y22},{x3,y23}...} and so on. This will allow me to determine parameters associated with each data_i, I=1..13

Comment: @thils That's what is stored in `op` isn't it?

Comment: @thils, you need to be clear in your question. I'm not sure what you really want.

Comment: It is true that the info. is contained in "op", but can you separate it into separate data sets...data1=..., data2=..... This may be simple, but I can't recall whether you use "Take" command. How do you break up "op" into smaller bits

Comment: @thils, you can just do `data1 = op[[1]]`, `data2 = op[[2]]` etc.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another somewhat shorter method:

```
Thread @ {#, {##2}} & @@@ data\[Transpose]
```

And this may be somewhat faster than other methods:

```
Inner[List, data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 2 ;;]], List]
```

Comment: Inner always amazes me.

Answer (score 0):

For instance, data1 and data13 can be obtained using

```
 x = data[[All, 1]];

    data1 = Transpose[Sort[MapThread[
           Function[xpt, {xpt, #} & /@ #2][#1] &, {x, Rest /@ data}]]][[1]] // TableForm

    data13 = Transpose[Sort[MapThread[Function[xpt, {xpt, #} & /@ #2][#1] &, {x, Rest /@ data}]]][[13]] // TableForm
```